# Synchronize Mysql Tables, and Update tables on either side

Tags: mysql, synchronization

Have two mysql databases in two servers, I have to share user information tables on both databases,I am using the both database for different projects, In both projects the user information need to be updated, So that update of user information should reflect in others, Please Suggest good methods to synchronize, so that in secure way no data get loosed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You can synchronize tables in two different databases with a help of [Date Comparison tool](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/database-synchronization.html) in dbForge Studio for MySQL. You can run it in command line mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, mysql's replication support Master -> Slave model. User can only read from Slave to avoid data conflict.
But some solution support master-master model. you can read this url for more details.
http://www.howtoforge.com/mysql_master_master_replication